# Android Php web application

Tags: php, android, web

Ok, so I am very new to android but I have some experience with PHP. I have a website for my college festival where there is a login system and registered users can take the quiz everything.( I am using Codeigniter as my PHP framework
Now I have been asked to make an android app for the festival. So , my question is , How do I connect my android application to the stuff on my website.

For example: I have a login system on my website and I want to reflect the same functionality in my android app i.e How to send the username and password to be authenticated and how the request will be processed on the server side? How do I connect my android application to my database ?

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

P.S : Yes, I get that I can very easily just make a mobile version of the website as suggested by many people. But since I want to learn Android, I think this would be a good opportunity for me to do so.

Comment: um...or just add a mobile css for the site? don't see how this applied to an application

Comment: Yes I know. I can very easily do that. But I want to learn Android, so I thought this would be a good opportunity for me to do so.

Comment: If you want to learn how to create apps for the Android platform, then here are some basic tutorils to get you started.  http://www.vogella.de/android.html and http://www.vogella.de/java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a service using PHP which takes required parameters and responds with JSON Object response. In your app you can use HTTPClient and JSonObject to parse the response and populate the app. Here is a sample on how to do [Android PHP MySQL example](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/)

If you don't need native mobile APP, then as other members suggested, you may add mobile css to your existing site.